# lldb assertion failure when attempting to print vector

Tags: c++, clang, lldb

I get the error

> > lldb: /home/hannes/.llvm/llvm/tools/clang/lib/AST/RecordLayoutBuilder.cpp:2271: uint64_t ::RecordLayoutBuilder::updateExternalFieldOffset(const clang::FieldDecl *, uint64_t): Assertion `ExternalFieldOffsets.find(Field) != ExternalFieldOffsets.end() && "Field does not have an external offset"' failed.
> >     Aborted (core dumped)

when I try to print a `vector<string>`. Does anyone know why this happens, and how to fix it? The equivalent works just fine in gdb (there are a number of reason why I'd rather use / *have* to use lldb over gdb).

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 with llvm, clang and lldb trunk.

The program, build instructions and lldb command sequence:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::for_each;
using std::begin;
using std::end;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec{"Hello","World","!"};
    for_each(begin(vec),end(vec),[](const std::string& s) {
    std::cout << s << " ";
      });
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
clang++ -g -c -std=c++11 main.cpp
clang++ -std=c++11 main.o -o test
```

---

```
lldb test 
Current executable set to 'test' (x86_64).
(lldb) break -n main
invalid command 'breakpoint -n'
(lldb) breat set -n main
error: 'breat' is not a valid command.
(lldb) break set -n main
Breakpoint 1: where = test`main + 26 at main.cpp:5, address = 0x0000000000400aea
(lldb) run
Process 24489 launched: '/home/hannes/Documents/Programming/CXX/test/test' (x86_64)
Process 24489 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x5fa9, 0x0000000000400aea test`main + 26 at main.cpp:5, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000000400aea test`main + 26 at main.cpp:5
   2    #include <string>
   3    
   4    int main() {
-> 5        std::vector<std::string> vec{"Hello","World","!"};
   6        return 0;
   7    }
n
Process 24489 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x5fa9, 0x0000000000400c72 test`main + 418 at main.cpp:6, stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x0000000000400c72 test`main + 418 at main.cpp:6
   3    
   4    int main() {
   5        std::vector<std::string> vec{"Hello","World","!"};
-> 6        return 0;
   7    }
frame variable
lldb: /home/hannes/.llvm/llvm/tools/clang/lib/AST/RecordLayoutBuilder.cpp:2271: uint64_t <anonymous namespace>::RecordLayoutBuilder::updateExternalFieldOffset(const clang::FieldDecl *, uint64_t): Assertion `ExternalFieldOffsets.find(Field) != ExternalFieldOffsets.end() && "Field does not have an external offset"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Log output with debug level 10:

```
Logging from function (<frame object at 0x3172f20>, '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lldb/formatters/cpp/gnu_libstdcpp.py', 141, '__init__', ['\t\tlogger = lldb.formatters.Logger.Logger()\n'], 0)
Providing synthetic children for a map named vec
Logging from function (<frame object at 0x3170d10>, '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lldb/formatters/cpp/gnu_libstdcpp.py', 214, 'update', ['\t\tlogger = lldb.formatters.Logger.Logger()\n'], 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the same thing happen if you say frame variable --raw?
This command is meant to dump your vector disabling data formatters. In the specific case you will get (assuming no crashes) the in-memory layout of the vector instead of the printout of the strings you stored there.
I am mostly trying to figure out if the data formatters are or not a part in this issue.

Comment: `frame variable --raw` works as expected. So yeah, it appears the data formatters are the problem.

Comment: Interesting. In order to help figure it out, just before you try to dump the vector, type:

script lldb.formatters.Logger._lldb_formatters_debug_level = 10

script lldb.formatters.Logger._lldb_formatters_debug_filename = /tmp/lldb.log (or any equivalent file name)

then type the command. the log should contain some info to help figure out where LLDB crashed

Comment: This dies in update(). What update does is (bulk of the work):
   impl = self.valobj.GetChildMemberWithName('_M_impl')
   self.start = impl.GetChildMemberWithName('_M_start')
   self.finish = impl.GetChildMemberWithName('_M_finish')
   self.end = impl.GetChildMemberWithName('_M_end_of_storage')
   self.data_type = self.start.GetType().GetPointeeType()
   self.data_size = self.data_type.GetByteSize()

Comment: A good way to figure this out would be to add after each like in update() (it is at the path that you see in the log entry) lines to the effect of logger >> “I did this”, logger >> “I did that” and see what the step that dies is. If it turns out that we die while retrieving stuff, it might be time for a BugZilla report.

Comment: As an aside, logging for the LLDB data formatters is not optimal for a number of reasons (mainly, the LLDB API does not expose access to the internal debugger logging facility, so the formatters end up having their own logger implementation - and regardless this is kept to a minimum for performance reasons)